# Can't resolve '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm using fontawesome icons with my React app, and I'm trying to install them **globally**.
Where should I specifically include the library containing the icons like this in my app?

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';
library.add(faFontAwesome)
```

Comment: Did the answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit difficult to say with so few details, but if you are using npm you should install them with the following command:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

To install them globally you use the `--global` or `-g` command:

```
npm install --global @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```